# PromQL: Taking max of duplicate times in series

Tags: prometheus, promql

I know our data might be the problem.   But I'm asking anyways.

We are using Prometheus to gather data from within our Kubernetes cluster.  It appears that some of our metrics have multiple entries for some and overlapping timestamps, but some slightly different labels included in the metric.  This causes the "sum by" function to add those duplicate timestamps to appear to be double.

Real simple example:

```
metric  time   labels                          value

cpu     1      pod="app1",endpoint="http"      1
cpu     2      pod="app1",endpoint="http"      1
cpu     3      pod="app1",endpoint="http"      .5
cpu     4      pod="app1",endpoint="http"      1
cpu     5      pod="app1",endpoint="http"      .5

cpu     3      pod="app1",endpoint="https"     .5
cpu     4      pod="app1",endpoint="https"     1
```

---

These are very simple example, but hopefully enough to show the issue.

When I do something like:

```
sum(max_over_time(cpu{pod="app1"}[24h:5m])) by(pod)
```

I end up getting the max of (2), where it adds (sum) both of the time(4)'s together.  I would expect the max to come back as (1).

I would be great if it could combine both series, take the max of either, then use that one.  But I'm not sure if this is possible.

Any help on normalizing this data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the `endpoint` from the `max_over_time()` result so that you don't have two rows in the set that is passed to `sum() by(pod)`.

Perhaps something like:

```
sum(max(max_over_time(cpu{pod="app1"}[24h:5m])) by(pod)) by(pod)
```

or

```
sum(max(max_over_time(cpu{pod="app1"}[24h:5m])) without(endpoint)) by(pod)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I didn't use your answer directly, but it helped me figure out what I could do.  I ended up using:

max(max_over_time(cpu{pod="app1"}[24h:5m])) by(pod)

Totally did what I needed.  But your answer helped me understand how to agregate the data more.  Big thanks!